# Is it important to convert numeric features to object if they have no ordinal or mathematical meaning?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-engineering, categorical-encoding

For example a column containing numeric values for phone area code or a postal code.

In case it matters, I am preprocessing data for use in a tree-based ensemble classifier.

Comment: You might get contradictory answers to this question, because a close version of it has been controversial.  See https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2005-07821-008.

Comment: I guess I am interested in common practices from people here. To me, it makes more intuitive sense for a tree to make a split on a numeric representation of the categorical variable where I control the encoding method. But I don't know if I'm wasting my time doing this.

Comment: The whole point of the paper I referenced is that sometimes the "common practice" is the inferior one.  Useful information can be lurking in the numerical representations of variables that appear to be purely nominal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is important, otherwise, a model cannot correctly learn effects for individual factors. However, some tree-based implementations do not do that because it is computationally more efficient to have one variable with 100 numeric values than to have 100 dummy variables, and a tree will eventually split all levels anyway, so the arbitrary ordering is not such a big issue as it is in other models, like linear regression.

If there is information "accidentally" encoded in the numeric code, then I would argue that you should still treat them as categorical variables and instead put that information explicitly in your model. So if a zip code is roughly related to geographic location, then it would be better to put the categorical zipcode in location to your model explicitly than treating zipcode as a numeric feature and hoping a model will figure it out. Also, if there is some information encoded in the numerical values, you should be extra cautious because this might lead to data leakage problems